# Ordering ID using order by in UCanAccess

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, sql-order-by, ucanaccess

I am using ucanaccess to link my database to my code but whenever I run it it doesnt work as I intend it to if it even runs at all. I just want to reorder the primary key (ID) into numerical order using ORDER BY ID;. When I edit the database it doesnt reorder when I run the method, it just pushes the edited ID to the bottom and orders them there. I am also confused if I should use an array sort in order to reorganize the entire table? Any help is appreciated. This runs whenever I attempt to edit the table in the GUI.

[Source code google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_gu_KIq3rOWUhmBWpp6Yt-sV7xwN_zQ4)

```
public void reorder()
{


for(int i = 0 ; i < size - 1;i++)
{        
    for(int j = i+1 ; j< size;j++)
    {
        if(launch[i].getID() > launch[j].getID())
        {
            Launch temp = launch[i];
            launch[i] = launch[j];
            launch[j] = temp;
            System.out.println(launch[i]);                
        }
    }
}
}
public void orderByID()
{                   
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM LaunchPriceList ORDER BY ID DESC"; 
    try
    {          
      dbman.updateQuery(sql);
      //reorder();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error Order by: " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The SQL ORDER BY clause if used for _retrieving_ data in a specific order. The actual rows in the database are (in most databases) not stored in any specific/guaranteed order. What is it that you actually need to do?

Comment: I am trying to  reorder the jTable according to the ID using this sql statement, as I said I am not sure whether or not I actually need to reorder the array containing the fields. So I want the fields to be ordered by ID, here is the source code for netbeans,I will update the main question

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to access your code (for whatever the n/w restrictions). Having said that...

You can start off by creating a custom implementation of [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) by extending [AbstractTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html)

Coming to populating the TableModel, you start with iterating through the result set and creating a TreeSet with a custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares the ID attribute.

once done, you can create the table with the previously populated table model. E.g.

```
JTable t = new JTable(model);
```

Updating the TableModel with refreshed data will automatically refresh the table.

Comment: But what would an example be of updating the table?

Comment: If you are asking about refreshing table view, updating the TableModel will automatically refresh the view.